# How to restore WP site missing the database?

Tags: database, restore

I have acquired a poorly backed up site. The owner should have done an export but instead just copied the 3 folders and a few files at the top area.  Can the site be recreated without the database, or will I need to start over?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you will need to start over.

Without the database or an export it is practically impossible to recreate the site.

There is no physical storage of content inside the WordPress filestructure. In rare cases the physical MySQL files can be found and used to import but, again, this is something dependant on the export you received. If its only the wp-admin and so on there most likely nog going to be there.